# To create dynamic tables in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a scenario where I need to put my CSV files into multiple tables. These table names will be different or unknown until run time. How can I create the SSIS package to load data into a unknown table name. To be specific, I have a table A and table B. Structure of both these tables are same. Today they maybe called Table A and Table B, but they may change to table C and table D with same structure. Now, I want to write a ssis package to load data into these 2 tables, but since the table names change all the time, I do not know on how to accomplish this
Thanks!

I do not know where to begin from

Comment: To restate: you have two template tables, A and B. When the SSIS package runs, it will load data to a clone of A or B?

Comment: If I have that correct, how do you whether the package should use A or B as a template? What is the logic for naming the table clone?

Comment: Nobody can really help you here because your problem is so vague. You need to provide some details about the logic of what the dynamic names should be in order for others to understand the problem.

Comment: What is the mechanism by which the table names are "changed"?  You'd potentially need to circumvent that process and write off a record that sets the "current" names of the tables - you could then look that up in the SSIS package to get the table names

Answer (score 0):

you can use recordeset destination

you need variable of type Object and then drag recordset destination which you need to set up to put the data in that variable.
More to read about it here: [a link]https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/use-a-recordset-destination?view=sql-server-ver16

You don't need to have a table to keep the data there. It is basically to put it in variable. Next you can create data flow for each table you need and use that variable as a source to pick the columns you need.
Another interesting thing in this scenario is derived columns. Look it up and see, it might help you.